# Use effect function in React says to import while it ends up working fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[Code highlighted in GitHub](https://github.com/gamer-12748/website/blob/ac33e694d6a15c9e9eed268a0326a476b9f11679/src/Component/pages/Testimonials.js#L62-L67)

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function getTok() {
    await Gettestimon();
    alldoc.map(forget => console.log(forget.name));
    setcondi(true);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }
  getTok();
}, []);
```

Whenever I compile the highlighted code, it says my function *gettestimon* which stands for getting a testimonial, not something else, is not imported in effect's, but then it ends up working anyway. I would like to know how to fix this, but I read somewhere and added:

`// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

How can I fix this?

The exact error is:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'Gettestimon'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

This is the website where it is used:

*https://www.aayushgarg.net/testimonials*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using external functions/variables inside `React.useEffect`, you need to add them to its dependency array as well. This way, React will know to run the `React.useEffect` only when the values specified in the dependency array changes. Plus, you won't need to use the eslint comment.

While it still works without adding it to the dependencies array, it will decrease the performance of your component with too many unnecessary re-renders.

You could improve it to something like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
  async function getTok() {
    await Gettestimon();
    alldoc.map(forget => console.log(forget.name));
    setcondi(true);
  }
  getTok();
}, [Gettestimon]);
```

To learn more about the `React.useEffect`, I'd suggest reading their official documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Answer (score -1):

This is due to a missing dependency.

The *useEffect* method is called for each render with the second argument being empty.  But if you need your *useEffect* function to execute when only something changes, we need to add that variable or object to the dependency array.

In using Effect, you used external objects out of function scope like alldoc and Gettestimon.

If you want to execute *useEffect* only with these object changes, *alldoc* and *Gettestimo*, you need to add it in the dependency array. Otherwise, you will send up in executing *useEffect* for each render cycle.

Comment: "The useEffect method is called for each render with the second argument being empty" this is *dead wrong*. If you have an empty dependency array it will run **once**, on the *initial render*. The danger with not having exhaustive deps is not too *many* renders but too *few*.